# Getting 2560x1600 resolution from RPi 4B on HP LP3065 monitor

Tags: hdmi, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I have an HP LP3065 workstation monitor which is 10+ years old and it only has 3 DVI-D Dual-link inputs. You can see its specs [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-lp3065-30-inch-widescreen-lcd-monitor/3297215/document/c00870358). It can only work in native resolution 2560x1600 or quarter resolution (1280x800).

I previously tried using it with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but due to the HDMI port limitations on Pi 3 I couldn't.

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4GB) which comes with 2 HDMI 2.0 ports and claims to support even 4K resolutions. So I wanted to give it another go this time pairing my monitor with the Pi 4.

I connected the two using a 24+1 DVI-D Dual-link to HDMI cable. I installed the latest Raspbian via NOOBS and I was able to see an image during the procedure (not sure about the resolution at that time), but after the first restart and booting into the Raspbian, there was no longer any image shown on the monitor. Since I enabled SSH from the beginning (by putting an empty `ssh` file on the SD card), I was able to connect through SSH from another PC.

I tried several things (*from StackExchange & other sites*) regarding changing `config.txt` but nothing helped in regards to using the native 2560x1600 resolution (*probably because most of them were not recent*). So I wanted to start a new question with fresh answers.

Currently, I can see the Raspbian desktop when I switch to 1280x800 but as I mentioned it is not enough. Where do we go from here? What are my next steps? Please elaborate...

Comment: There's been people reporting problems with HDMI conversion cables (usually to VGA) since the model 1B.  The issue is I believe that they sink an excess of power and so may not work or may work poorly.

Comment: Do you know of any HDMI to DVI-D DL active adapter? Or would an HDMI to DisplayPort active adapter + DisplayPort to DVI-D DL dongle work together for my desired result?